# How can I display a list variable in a view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

### Question

Why can my viewmodel not iterate through my List Books variable?

### Code

**Model Definitions**

```
public class Shelf
{
    public int bookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
}

public class Book
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public Shelf shelf { get; set; }
    }

public class ReadViewModel
    {
        public int ShelfId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller seems to be fine since I am able to display ShelfId and Name for the ReadViewModel. **Edit** I have the action method it at the request of users here.

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult Details(int ShelfId)
    {
        //find the right building for edit
        var shelfs = from shelf in applicationDBContext.Shelfs
                                         where shelf.ShelfId == ShelfId
                                         select shelf;

        ReadViewModel readViewModel = new ReadViewModel
        {
            ShelfId = shelfs.First().ShelfId,
            Name = shelfs.First().Name,
            Books = shelfs.First().Books, //Error still present despite this
        };
        return View("Details", readViewModel);
    }
```

I know, I should be using async and await in the above, but I am teaching myself mvc, vnext, and etc. So using the above to teach me how the flow works before I use more "best practices".

**View**

```
 @model Application.Model.ReadViewModel
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Shelf Details";
    }


<h1>Building Details</h1>
<table>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ShelfId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model=>model.ShelfId)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Name)</td>
        </tr>
     </table>
<h2>Rooms</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Books.First().BookId)</td>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Books.First().Name)</td>
    </tr>

    @*@foreach (var book in Model.Books)
    {

    }*@

    @*@for(var booksIndex = 0; booksIndex < Model.Books.Count(); booksIndex++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Books[booksIndex].BookId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => model.Books[booksIndex].Name)</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    }*@
</table>
```

### Problem

I keep getting an error like `Value cannot be null` or something like `Object instance cannot be null` when I try to iterate through rooms with either a for or a foreach. *If I comment out the loops, I can display the shelf id and name.*

### Attempts

This doesn't make sense to me. At one time I had no data for books given the shelf, so I thought that was the issue. So I put in some data and I still get the exact same error. So I am convinced that my view is unable to iterate through my books and list them.

Both loops as given above give no errors until I try to access the view through the browser.

Comment: Even though controller works fine, it still might be relevant. Can you please post code for the action that builds the model for this view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea controller is important and also how the data is being bound. How are you population the model? What framework are you using? Entiry, Linq2SQL, dapper?

The reason you are getting null or object is not set, is clearly because those values are not set. Nobody is trying to trick you.

The project will compile fine because the code syntax is correct, at build time. The reason you get errors at the view, known as runtime errors, is because the data that is being bound is incorrect or missing. The compiler cannot verify against runtime data... because it doesn't know anything about that.

With Visual Studio you can set a break point in the View, on the @code section. I would suggest setting a break point right at the first loop. Click on the far left margin to get a red dot.

[image]

Run the site in Debug (F5) and Visual Studio will stop at the break point on the View. You can then inspect your `Model` or `List<Model>` and see what data is there. Make sure the properties you need are populated.  *(The image shows the breakpoint hit after running debug. A yellow line appears and you can hover over variables to inspect the values or right click them and add them to the watch panel)*

That is the only reason you will get these errors at runtime.

Comment: OK great, that rules out lazy loading... I hope. Please try and inspect the Model at runtime to see what data is in there. I am sure that will lead you back to the problem.

Comment: By putting the debug in view and seeing what is the ReadViewModel, right?

Comment: OK yea. You can put a break point on the Return View and insped the readviemwodel. But really, you should be calling `.ToList()` to force EF to get the entire List before returning the view. `...Book.ToList()`  **otherwise its an IEnumarable and can only be iterated once!**

Comment: I think I understand your comment, you mean Books = shelfs.First().Books.ToList() in my action method, yes?

Comment: You also don't really needs a "ViewModel" like you created if your models are linked to each other with Foreign keys. I can see you are a complete beginner here, which may be the problem but no worries. Idealy you just want to to get the Book by ID. Then on the View you can do `Model.Shelf.ShelfID` thanks to lazy loading and foreign keys. Also you are getting a list of shelves and then getting the first of each. That is upside down and incorrect (inefficient)

Comment: If you are selectin a shelf by ID, then why are you getting a list of shelfes from the DBContext? Just get the single shelf and then do ,  `shelf.Name` and `shelf.Books.ToList()`  I Use Lambda. So I would do this. `var _shelf = DB.Shelfs.Single(x => x.shelfID == ShelfID)` Then you access the foreign nodes thanks to constraints and foreign keys... assuming you have done that?

Comment: This was great. The reason I did a viewmodel was so I would only display a reduced fields or have the ability to do stats between those two tables in the future by having a viewmodel. Is this not the right way to do things then? Where are some reading resources, including books you could recommend? Especially on lazyloading and EF. Thanks.

Comment: Yea there is NO 1 book. I just try and find blogs written by asp guys. Like Scott Gu did allot. Try Virtual Academy and following some ASP.NET Tutorials. The rest you pick up when you need to tweak things and make it better. EF already gives you "reduced" fields, until you need them by calling ToList() or doing a ".Where" or similar. It DOESNT load all the data associated with the primary entity, that would be pointless :] Slow :] and stupid ;] You can force it, but that is extra options. Wait till you get to Entity States :) Thats fun :P

Comment: Are you also learning vNext as well? I think I have seen your name as contributing and finding issues on asp.net github repo.

Comment: Yea I am. I just got MVC running on nginx :) A tutorial on my blog will show up soon. http://pkula.blogspot.com and also http://pumk.in will be the hosted MVC on nginx. (Just give it a few days - I need to tweak some things) - Wierd Linux week. I also just installed Ubuntu Touch onto my Nexus 7 :P heheh

Comment: Cool, I'll follow you on there and maybe on twitter. I'll tweet you soon. Please follow me in return. :)